# iPhone UI Widget Sizing

Tags: ios, iphone, layout, user-interface

I am laying out an interface in code within a view controller and it appears that I need to provide explicit sizing even for standard, simple widgets like buttons and labels (one would think they have intrinsic dimensions).

Does Apple publish official standard dimensions for these widgets?

How is this situation usually handled when interface builder is not being used?

Answer (score 1):

For label there is not any standard dimensions but for buttons you should keep **size of 44 X 44 px** , so user can easily tap on it..

Make it easy for people to interact with content and controls by giving each interactive element ample
spacing. Give tappable controls a hit target of about 44 x 44 points. From 
iOS Human Interface Guidelines - [Apple Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/.../mobilehig/MobileHIG.pdf%E2%80%8E)

Check this [standard-iphone-element-sizes](http://jdg.net/post/106465937/standard-iphone-element-sizes) blog.

Comment: so when I look at 10 different iPhone apps and their UI elements appear to have similar sizing, padding, and margins, this is just coincidence?

Answer (score 1):

I serached the document about iOS picture size, please see the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000967-TP6).

App icon resource sizes

Filename      /     Size of canvas (in pixels)

icon_512x512@2x  /    1024 x 1024

icon_512x512     /     512 x 512

icon_256x256@2x    /    512 x 512

icon_256x256      /     256 x 256

icon_128x128@2x    /     256 x 256

icon_128x128     /     128 x 128

icon_32x32@2x   /     64 x 64

icon_32x32    /     32 x 32

icon_16x16@2x   /    32 x 32

icon_16x16   /    16 x 16

And in the program, follw iphone screen size,
width - 320
heigh - 480, so base on these sizes, you can adjust your picture.

(especially, twice the resolution for iPhone, 640*960 is nessary!)